# Easiest web service

Tags: java, php, web-services, rest, soap

I want to do a quick development of an Android application which comunicates with a web services and it saves the information in a data base.

I have experience developing WCF webservice, but I think it's a bit too much for a quick development like this. So, I was thinking of developing a really easy and fast web services, but outside .NET and its WCF, I dont know too much.

Which technology do you recommend me? Rest, soap, ...
And which lenguage? Php, java...

Thanks

Comment: What is "too much"? Using WCF and Entity Framework I can have a web service that stores and retreives data up and running in literally a few minutes.

Comment: This is not a good question for SO. Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @CodeCaster I refered to publish the web service. With .NET is a bit complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO: REST + PHP will be easiest, both to write then use - PHP has elementary Apache (and other webservers) integration, language built-in tools to communicate with a db and everything else needed for a simple webservice. There are even some minimalistic frameworks to help you set that up in literally minutes - check here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238125/best-framework-for-php-and-creation-of-restful-based-web-services